# Windows: Unused software has been updated

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, skype

The notification "Skype has been updated" just popped up in my Windows 10 notification center.

This windows install is about 4 months old, I've never used Skype before and cannot find anything related to it in the Task Manager's startup, processes or services tab.

The Skype app is the UWP version 12.1815.209.0

As Skype is owned by Microsoft, it probably updated automatically via windows-update.

How could I go about disabling these updates?
I'm guessing uninstalling Skype is easiest (I hadn't even realized it's installed), but might it come back with future windows updates?

Is there a list of applications which may be auto-updated by Windows which I could disable to prevent bandwidth and storage space being used up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I go about disabling these updates?

1. Open Microsoft Store
2. Click the **Settings** button

[image]

3. Click **Settings**

[image]

4. Turn **Update apps automatically** to **Off**

[image]

5. Done

> I'm guessing uninstalling Skype is easiest (I hadn't even realized it's installed), but might it come back with future windows updates?

When you install a feature update it will be reinstalled.

> Is there a list of applications which may be auto-updated by Windows which I could disable to prevent bandwidth and storage space being used up?

This list is continuously changing.  It's easier to just uninstall the applications you don't want then prevent your UWP applications from aromatically updating.